# Change the text color of multiple elements in a list with a:hover

Tags: html, hover, html-lists

So, I have this list contained within a specific id.  I only want to manipulate the link colors for this specific id, which is #icon-header.  So here is the problem:

I want the whole li element to be the link, but instead of having the background color change on hover, I want all of the text elements to to the color #2BA6CB.  And no matter where the user clicks, I want the whole li element to be the link.

So, I was wondering if there was something wrong with where I am putting the a tag, and also what your suggestions were for the css of it all.

The i tag is a webfont.  I need that to change with the h4 and the p tag all at the same time when the user hovers over the li.

Any help would be amazing.  Here is the html:

```
 <div class="row hide-for-small" id="icon-header" align="center">

    <ul class="large-block-grid-6 small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-6">
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <i class="fi-male size-60"></i>
            <h4>Ready</h4>
            <p>Create a personal health and fitness profile.</p>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <i class="fi-checkbox size-60"></i>
            <h4>Set</h4>
            <p>Set goals and chart your progress.</p>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <i class="fi-upload-cloud size-60"></i>
            <h4>Go</h4>
            <p>Upload your exercise data from anywhere.</p>
            </a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <i class="fi-graph-bar size-60"></i>
            <h4>Learn</h4>
            <p>View real results and develop healthy patterns.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `a`-tag the dimensions (width & height) of the `li` Element instead of styling the `li` Element. Then you will have the effect, that you can click the whole highlighted area instead of only the link.

To give an inline element like ´a´-Tag a width and height you need to give it ´display:block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the 'a' tag display: block in the css. Note that wrapping an anchor tag around block level elements is *only* allowed in html5. Older specs explicitly disallow it.